# css scroll-snap property skips following pages

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a website with a total of three pages. My idea was to add a horizontal scroll snapping effect. My problem is that it doesn't snap to the next page, instead pages are getting skipped and it snaps to the last one. I use mandatory snap points.

Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <h1>Page One</h1>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1>Page Two</h1>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1>Page Three</h1>
        </section>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**SCSS**

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;

  .container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: flex;

    section {
      flex: none;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      scroll-snap-align: start;

      &:nth-of-type(1) {
        background-color: rgb(28, 28, 28);
        color: beige;
      }

      &:nth-of-type(2) {
        background-color: rgb(38, 38, 38);
        color: beige;
      }

      &:nth-of-type(3) {
        background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
        color: beige;
      }

      h1 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe is the [default behavior](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/):

> By default, scroll snapping only kicks in when the user stops scrolling, meaning they can skip over several snap points before coming to a stop.

In order to stop scrolling at every "page" (every child of the scroll container), there is a setting called `scroll-snap-stop: always`, which must be applied to the children of the scroll container. However, this [does not work in every browser](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-snap-stop) yet.